# script to generate the machine name

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I want to generate a JSON file with the name of the machine like the following:

```
{
  "machineName": "Machine-Name98"
}
```

How can I start with this? Is there any site or example to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: As you tagged your question with "batch-file": does `%computername%` help? (`echo %computername%`)

Comment: How can I create a JSON file and put the computername on it?

Comment: With batch? `echo { >json`, `echo "machineName": "%computername%" >>json`, `echo } >>json`, `type json`

Answer (score 1):

Try out this simple code:

```
Echo %computername%>json
```

Hope it helps